# Java replace all string, replacing all numbers less than 3

Tags: java

```
public static enum pie {
    APPLE_PIE1(1, 250),
    PUMPKIN_PIE1(2, 300),
    OTHER_PIE1(3, 350),
    APPLE_PIE2(4, 400),
    OTHER_PIE2(5, 450),
    PUMPKIN_PIE2(6, 500),
    APPLE_PIE3(7, 550),
    ;
    private static Map<Integer, pie> pie = new HashMap<Integer, pie>();
    static {
        for(pie pie : pie.values()) {
            pie.put(pie.getId(), pie);
        }
    }

    public static pie forId(int id) {
        return pie.get(id);
    }

    private pie(int id, double exp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    public int id;
    public double exp;


    System.out.println("My favorite type of pie is " + pie.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", " ").replaceAll("2", "").replaceAll("3", "").replaceAll("4", "") + ".");
```

Example code ripped up, but how would I make that '.replaceAll("*number*", "")' replace all numbers less than or equal to 4 with a more simple code? Creating a new .replaceAll 3 times is redundant. If I do...:

```
    double number[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    pie.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("_", " ").replaceAll(number.toString(), "") + ".");
```

...I'll get a nasty error.

Here's the error...

```
SEVERE: An error occurred in an executor service! The server will be halted immediately.
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 9
[D@12452e8
        ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show the error- Do you expect us to run the program ourself?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct syntax? The last line seems to end with a random `)` which I don't think should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error, you should just replace

```
double number[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

by

```
String number = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
```

But I would not use replaceAll to do that. Instead, I would add a `label` field to your enum, in a similar way as the other fields, and call `getLabel()` instead of `toString()`, or override `toString()` to return the label:

```
public static enum pie {
    APPLE_PIE1(1, 250, "apple pie"),
    PUMPKIN_PIE1(2, 300, "pumpkin pie"),
    ...

    private int id;
    private double exp;
    private String label;

    private pie(int id, double exp, String label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.exp = exp;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    // optional: I wouldn't do it as it would make debugging harder
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}
```